# Problema con carpeta de ruta en instalacion de Node.js

Tags: nodejs, instalacion

Estoy instalando el programa, al corroborar con el cmd quiero ingresar la ruta de mi carpeta y no me la reconoce. Cuando me pide la ruta donde van a ir, cuando copio y pego la ruta de la carpeta y doy enter, no me aparece como si fuera que estoy `dentro` de esa carpeta. puede ser que la descarga de realiza en un disco `C:` y yo toda la información y documentos de los proyectos y ademas los tengo en el disco `D:`? cómo puedo hacer para que me reconozca la ruta en otro disco?.

Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

solo revisa que Node este agregado a las variables de sistema. En tu caso abre un `cmd` o un `PowerShell` y digita lo siguiente **node --version**. Debe mostrarle algo como esto: `v16.0.0`. Con eso puedes ejecutar node desde cualquier directorio sin importar la ruta en la que te encuentres.

Por lo tanto si tienes un proyecto en `Angular` por ejemplo, debes ingresar al directorio donde tienes tu proyecto y ejecutar el comando correspondiente para dicho proyecto, suponiendo este caso simplemente seria ejecutar `ng serve`